# Matplotlib UserWarning - redundantly defined marker

Tags: matplotlib

Getting this warning from matplotlib, i tried setting the fmt, but it didnt work for me (perhaps did it wrong tho). I did suppress warnings and it worked, but i dont want to suppress all python warnings as i think this should be possible to fix. Thanks for any help.

> UserWarning: marker is redundantly defined by the 'marker' keyword
> argument and the fmt string "o" (-> marker='o'). The keyword argument
> will take precedence.   axs[0].plot_date(app.plot_dates, app.values,
> linestyle='-', marker="", color='#F9D96D', linewidth=1.5)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the fmt to an empty string?

I was able to bypass this warning by passing the kwarg `fmt=""` (I was using `plot_date`)